# How can I calculate a new dataframe only for one outcome type?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with some data that involves participants running on a cognitive task that measures their outcome (Correct or Incorrect) and reaction time (RT) (the entire dataset is called practice). For each participant, I want to create a new dataframe with their average RT when they got the answer correct, and one for when they were incorrect. I've tried

```
    practice %>%
  mutate(correctRT = mean(practice$RT[practice$Outcome=="Correct"]))
```

Using dplyr and tidyverse, as well as

```
correctRT <- c(mean(practice$RT[practice$Outcome=="Correct"]))
```

(which I'm sure isn't the correct way to do it) and nothing seems to be working. I'm a complete novice and am working with this dataset in order to learn how to do stats with R and just can't find any answers with R.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. We can't see what you're working with, or what the output is that you say isn't working, or what exactly "not working" means here

Comment: You mix a bit `{tidyverse}` and `base-R` in your attempt. It is good to know about both as some things are more intuitively done in one or the other. Check below for a `{dplyr}`-only approach. I am not sure that you need to store/save out the different result data frames. The answer fails to deliver on this (I can update based on your needs). However, I do believe, there is probably no need for the dataframe-by-dataframe, if work on a grouped data frame and produce a summary. Let me know whether this is a possible output. Otherwise, we adapt according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In R you can "keep" multiple objects (e.g. data frames) in a single list. This saves you from storing every (sub)dataframe in a separate variable (e.g. through subsetting your problem and storing it based on Participant, Outcome). This will come handy when you have "many" individuals and a manual filter and storing of the (sub)dataframe becomes prohibitive.

Conceptually, your problem is to "subset" your data to the Participant and Outcome you aim for and calculate the mean on this group.

The following is based on `{tidyverse}`, i.e. `{dplyr}`.

**data**

As you have not provided a reproducble example, this is a quick hack of your data:

```
practice <- data.frame(
    Participant = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","D"),
    RT = c(10, 12, 14, 9, 12, 13, 17, 11, 13, 17),
    Outcome = c("Incorrect","Correct", "Correct","Incorrect","Incorrect","Correct", "Correct","Incorrect","Correct", "Correct")
)
```

which looks like the following:

```
practice
   Participant RT   Outcome
1            A 10 Incorrect
2            A 12   Correct
3            A 14   Correct
4            B  9 Incorrect
5            B 12 Incorrect
6            B 13   Correct
7            B 17   Correct
8            C 11 Incorrect
9            C 13   Correct
10           D 17   Correct
```

**splitting groups of a dataframe**

The `{tidyverse}` provides some neat functions for the general data processing.
`{dplyr}` has a `group_split()` function that returns such a list.

```
library(dplyr)

practice %>% group_split(Participant, Outcome)
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    Participant: character
    RT         : double
    Outcome    : character
>
>[7]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Participant    RT Outcome
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>  
1 A              12 Correct
2 A              14 Correct

[[2]]
...
```

You can address the respective list-elements with the `[[]]` notation.
Store the list in a variable and try `my_list_name[[3]]` to extract the 3rd element.

**potential summary for your problem**

If you do not need a list you could wrap this into a data summary.
If you want to split on Outcomes, you may want to filter your data in 2 sub-dataframes only holding the respective outcome (e.g. `correct <- practice %>% filter(Outcome == "Correct")`).

Group your data dependent on the summary you want to construct.
Use `summarise()` to summarise your groups into a 1-row summary.
Note you can combine multiple operations. For example next to the mean reaction time, the following counts the number of rows (:= attempts).

```
practice %>% 
  group_by(Participant, Outcome) %>% 

##--------- summarise data into 1 row summarise
  summarise( Mean_RT = mean(RT)    # calculate mean reaction time
            ,Attempts = n() )      # how many times
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Participant [4]
  Participant Outcome   Mean_RT Attempts
  <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>    <int>
1 A           Correct      13          2
2 A           Incorrect    10          1
3 B           Correct      15          2
4 B           Incorrect    10.5        2
5 C           Correct      13          1
6 C           Incorrect    11          1
7 D           Correct      17          1
```

Please note that this is a grouped data frame. If you further process the data, you need to "remove" the grouping. Otherwise any follow up operation in a pipe will be on the group-level.
For this you can either use `summarise(...., .groups = "drop")` or you add `... %>% ungroup()` to your pipe.

If you need to split the result, check for above `group_split()`.